# docker pip install not working with requirements file

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip, dockerfile

I am using docker to create a python container. Something wierd is happening, 
When I install something using pip, it works, and it's fine, when I try to use a requirements file, I get an error, the system does not find pip.

Ideas?

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest

RUN ["apt-get", "update" ,"-y"]

RUN ["apt-get", "upgrade","-y"]

RUN ["apt-get", "install", "python-pip", "python3-pip","-y"]

RUN ["apt-get", "update" ,"-y"]

RUN ["apt-get", "upgrade","-y"]

ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN ["pip", "install", "keras"]
```

works

while

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest

RUN ["apt-get", "update" ,"-y"]

RUN ["apt-get", "upgrade","-y"]

RUN ["apt-get", "install", "python-pip", "python3-pip","-y"]

RUN ["apt-get", "update" ,"-y"]

RUN ["apt-get", "upgrade","-y"]

ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "/requirements.txt"]
```

gets this error

> /bin/sh: 1: [pip,: not found

Comment: Usually that `[command,` in the error message is an indication that you haven't gotten the JSON-array quoting just right, though what you have in the question looks correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to remove all brackets and double-quotes to see if something changes. There is no reason to fail.